# How can my client upload ios app without give access to the source code?

Tags: ios, store, sign

How can I share the ios app with the client so that he signs it and uploads it to the store without giving him access to the source code?

Comment: Archive the app and then send it to the customer to sign it.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Window -> Orginizer then choose your archive and press "Distribute App" button. Then choose "App Store" then "Export" then you will go through the standard process of app signing (you need customer account signing certificate and provisioning profile which will be used by your customer to upload the app to the AppStore) and choosing directory to put your app. After that you can send the app to the customer.

After that your customer will be able to upload the app to the App Store Using Application Loader instrument in Xcode.